# python-meeting two column criteria in one dataset and outputting to a new list or printing count

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, append

This is a really simple question but I don't know what i'm doing wrong. 
I am basically trying to create a new list only if two columns in my data have a 1 in one of the columns and are listed as female in a separate column. Then I was going to count the number of observations in the new list. I can probably also not create the new list and just check if whether they meet the two conditions then count+1. But my main problem is that I don't think my if statement is even correct because when I create the list. It's blank. I already know that there are matches that meet the criteria so i know the array shouldn't be blank. 
am I being stupid?

Thanks for any help.

```
>>> data_s=[]
for i in data:
    if data[0::,1]=="1" and data[0::,4]=="female":
        data_s.append(i)
        data_s=numpy.array(data_s)

>>> data_s
[]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into conditional indexing, and then try something like this:

```
data_s = [entry for entry in data if entry[1]=="1" and entry[4]=="female"]
```

In your code segment, the if statement should probably be tested on i (not data) since you are using i to loop through the elements of data